# How to save data for each loop?

Tags: python

I want to save the dictionary  in Csv or mat file for each loop, the code is from the link [FHN equations](https://www.normalesup.org/%7Edoulcier/teaching/modeling/excitable_systems.html)

```
   import scipy.io as sio
    trajectory_nonauto = {} 
    file_out = f"out_{i}.mat"
    for i, param in enumerate(step_sc):
        flow = partial(non_autonomous_fitzhugh_nagumo, **param)
        for j, ic in enumerate(initial_conditions):
            trajectory_nonauto[i, j] = scipy.integrate.odeint(flow,y0=ic,t=time_span)
            sio.savemat(file_out, { trajectory_nonauto[i, j]})
            data = trajectory_nonauto
            print(trajectory_nonauto)
```

I was getting this error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray

at sio.savemat

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it [savemat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html) takes a dict as its second argument.

The thing you are trying to pass, `{ trajectory_nonauto[i, j]}`, is not a dict.

The error you are seeing is because `{x}` creates a set with element x, and all elements of a set must be hashable.

Comment: So how can I save them?

Comment: You can try the example code in the link, for example `sio.savemat(file_out,{"a":trajectory_nonauto[i, j]})`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `sio.savemat(file_out, { trajectory_nonauto[i, j]})`

try `sio.savemat(file_out, {"x-axis": trajectory_nonauto[i, j]})`

Comment: I was getting this error when I replace the line  'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: please try this sio.savemat(file_out, {"x-axis": trajectory_nonauto[i, j]}) , If this doesn't work can you please show what is yhe output of scipy.integrate.odeint(flow,y0=ic,t=time_span)